# JOLT - Reorder nested arrays

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I'm trying to use JOLT to reorder a nested array. My goal is to group all elements that are located in the same array position (i) and add them to another array.

Input:

```json
{
  "values": [
    [
      "84139",
      "123"
    ],
    [
      "230",
      "456"
    ],
    [
      "230475",
      "789"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Desired result:

```json
{
  "result": [ // same length as values[i]
    [ // same length as values
      "84139",
      "230",
      "230475"
    ],
    [
      "123",
      "456"
      "789"
    ]
  ]
}
```

**INFO**: keep in mind the length of both arrays' (root and child) length is variable so the solution has to be generic.

Additional input:

```json
{
  "values": [
    [
      "84139",
      "123",
      "000"
    ],
    [
      "230",
      "456",
      "000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Additional output:

```json
{
  "result": [
    [
      "84139",
      "230"
    ],
    [
      "123",
      "456"
    ],
    [
      "000",
      "000"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to get what you wanted.

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "values": {
        "*": {
          "*": "result.[&0]"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The secret here is matching the "leaf nodes" of values to the index they occupy in their respective arrays by using `&0`, which in this case indicates the array index of each leaf node.

Be aware that this solution will only work if all the children of `values` have the same number of children.